# CMake make install fails with "error:___ was not declared in this scope"

Tags: c++, cmake, compiler-errors

I'm relatively new to programming and running into a huge problems after deep search without finding a proper solution. I'm working on my own research project which is dependent on CMake package developed by somebody (source code can be found on GitHub).

I’m trying to compile the files using CMake 3.22.2 on Windows 10 64-bit using MinGW32-GCC 6.3.0. However, whenever I try to execute “make install” command, I’m kind of stuck on the following errors.

```
[  2%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/tn93.dir/src/TN93.cpp.obj
[  4%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/tn93.dir/src/stringBuffer.cc.obj
[  7%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/tn93.dir/src/tn93_shared.cc.obj
C:\Users\MaC\Downloads\New folder\tn93\src\tn93_shared.cc: In function 'int readFASTA(FILE*, char&, StringBuffer&, StringBuffer&, Vector&, Vector&, long int&, bool, Vector*, char, double)':
C:\Users\MaC\Downloads\New folder\tn93\src\tn93_shared.cc:717:14: error: 'flockfile' was not declared in this scope
   flockfile(F);
              ^
C:\Users\MaC\Downloads\New folder\tn93\src\tn93_shared.cc:722:40: error: 'getc_unlocked' was not declared in this scope
         int currentC = getc_unlocked (F);
                                        ^
C:\Users\MaC\Downloads\New folder\tn93\src\tn93_shared.cc:724:29: error: 'feof_unlocked' was not declared in this scope
         if (feof_unlocked (F))
                             ^
C:\Users\MaC\Downloads\New folder\tn93\src\tn93_shared.cc:834:35: error: 'funlockfile' was not declared in this scope
                     funlockfile (F);
                                   ^
C:\Users\MaC\Downloads\New folder\tn93\src\tn93_shared.cc:860:33: error: 'funlockfile' was not declared in this scope
                   funlockfile (F);
                                 ^
C:\Users\MaC\Downloads\New folder\tn93\src\tn93_shared.cc:874:21: error: 'funlockfile' was not declared in this scope
       funlockfile (F);
                     ^
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\tn93.dir\build.make:106: CMakeFiles/tn93.dir/src/tn93_shared.cc.obj] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:100: CMakeFiles/tn93.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:135: all] Error 2
```

Additional info, here's CMake call:

```
C:\Users\MaC\Downloads\New folder\tn93> cmake -G"MinGW Makefiles"
CMake Warning:
  No source or binary directory provided.  Both will be assumed to be the
  same as the current working directory, but note that this warning will
  become a fatal error in future CMake releases.


CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


-- The C compiler identification is GNU 6.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 6.3.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Could NOT find OpenMP_C (missing: OpenMP_C_FLAGS OpenMP_C_LIB_NAMES)
-- Could NOT find OpenMP_CXX (missing: OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS OpenMP_CXX_LIB_NAMES)
-- Could NOT find OpenMP (missing: OpenMP_C_FOUND OpenMP_CXX_FOUND)
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/MaC/Downloads/New folder/tn93
```

Here's file tree

```
├───CMakeFiles
│   ├───3.22.2
│   │   ├───CompilerIdC
│   │   │   └───tmp
│   │   └───CompilerIdCXX
│   │       └───tmp
│   ├───CMakeTmp
│   ├───fasta_diff.dir
│   │   └───src
│   ├───FindOpenMP
│   ├───NF.dir
│   ├───nucfreqsfasta.dir
│   │   └───src
│   ├───Progress
│   ├───readreduce.dir
│   │   └───src
│   ├───selectreads.dir
│   │   └───src
│   ├───seqcoverage.dir
│   │   └───src
│   ├───ShortestPathTN93.dir
│   │   └───src
│   ├───tn93-cluster.dir
│   │   └───src
│   ├───tn93.dir
│   │   └───src
│   ├───TN93SP.dir
│   └───validate_fasta.dir
│       └───src
├───data
└───src
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: The repo list the dependencies: gcc and cmake of certain versions. This list is incomplete. This repo also depends on being in a POSIX environment, which Windows isn't.

Comment: I tested compiling this with openmp and the current mingw with gcc-11.2 (using msys2) and it failed for different reasons so I gave up.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Is there a possibility to run a virtual environment or something like that on Windows?

Comment: You can attempt to run in WSL with an ubuntu-18.04. That may be closer to the build environment used to develop this. [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install)

Comment: On second thought. I compiled as a 64 bit executable since I do that always now. It appears the errors were not properly handling 64 bit. I can try again with 32 bit compiling.

Comment: @drescherjm I'll try to run it in WSL and see how it is

Comment: With 32 bit I got the same errors as you did.

Comment: @drescherjm That's frustrating. Thank you for testing it in both versions for me

Comment: Either WSL or Cygwin should work.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Update. You're absolutely right. I was able to successfully install the package via WSL with an Ubuntu 18.04. This repo really requires POSIX environment. Would you be able to write an answer so I can accept it? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the undefined/undeclared identifiers are POSIX functions. See e.g. [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/flockfile.html). They do not exist on Windows, or in C or C++ standards.

The software cannot be compiled as-is on a non-POSIX(-ish) system such as native Windows. It should be easy to run it on [WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/) or with [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/).